# Patterson's decoding algorithm for Goppa codes

Tags: post-quantum-cryptography, modular-arithmetic, coding-theory, code-based-cryptography

From [this Wiki page](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binary_Goppa_code): given a Goppa code $\Gamma(g, L)$ and a binary word $v=(v_0,...,v_{n-1})$, its syndrome is defined as $$s(x)=\sum_{i=0}^{n-1}\frac{v_i}{x-L_i} \mod g(x).$$
To do error correction, Patterson's algorithm goes as follows:

> - Calculate $$v(x)=\sqrt{s(x)^{-1}-x}\mod g(x)$$ (this assumes that $s(x)\ne 0$, which is always the case unless $v$ belongs to
>   $\Gamma(g,L)$ and no correction is required).
> - Use the EEA to obtain the polynomials $a(x)$ and $b(x)$ such that $$ a(x)=b(x)v(x)\mod g(x)$$
> - Calculate the polynomial $p(x)=a(x)+xb(x)^2$. Assuming that the original word is decodable, this should be the same as the factorized
>   *error locator* polynomial $$\sigma(x)=\prod_{i\in B}(x-L_i) $$ where $B=\{i \text{ s.t. } e_i\ne 0\}$.
> - Assuming that the original word is decodable (that is, $|B|<d$ where $d$ is the minimum distance of the code), we simply calculate the
>   roots of $\sigma(x)$: if $L_i$ is a root, then an error as occurred in
>   the $i$-th position.

I only have one question: how do we show that the polynomial $p(x)$ obtained in the third step corresponds exactly to $\sigma(x)$ as defined above?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First note that
$$\frac{\sigma'(x)}{\sigma(x)}=\sum_{i\in B}\frac 1{x-L_i}$$
and that if we write $C$ for the bit positions of a codeword, the Goppa code is defined by
$$\sum_{i\in C}\frac 1{x-L_i}\equiv 0\pmod{g(x)}$$
so that
$$\frac{\sigma'(x)}{\sigma(x)}\equiv\sum_{i\in B\ominus C}\frac 1{x-L_i}\pmod{g(x)}$$
and the right hand side is just $s(x)$.

We split $\sigma(x)$ into odd and even degree monomials so that we can find polynomials $\sigma_{odd}$ and$\sigma_{even}$ such that
$$\sigma(x)=x\sigma_{odd}(x^2)+\sigma_{even}(x^2). \qquad (1)$$
Because we are in a field of a characteristic 2, polynomials with only square terms are squares of other polynomials of degree at most $(\deg g-1)/2$ and we aim to recover $a(x)$ and $b(x)$ satisfying this degree bound such that $a(x)^2=\sigma_{even}(x^2)$ and $b(x)^2=\sigma_{odd}$.

Differentiating (1) gives
$$\sigma'(x)=\sigma_{odd}(x^2)$$
and so
$$\frac{\sigma(x)}{\sigma'(x)}=x+\frac{\sigma_{even}(x^2)}{\sigma_{odd}(x^2)}$$
which tells us that
$$\frac1{s(x)}-x\equiv \frac{\sigma_{even}(x^2)}{\sigma_{odd}(x^2)}\pmod{g(x)}.$$
Thus the polynomial $v(x)$ is equivalent to the rational function $a(x)/b(x)$ that we seek modulo $g(x)$. The extended Euclidean algorithm will return two polynomials such that
$$\frac{c(x)}{d(x)}\equiv v(x)\pmod{g(x)}$$
with $\deg c$ and $\deg d$ both less than $(\deg g)/2$ and these polynomials must be equal to our sought after $a(x)$ and $b(x)$ otherwise $a(x)d(x)-b(x)c(x)$ is a polynomial of degree less than $d$ and divisible by $g(x)$. Having recovered $a(x)$ and $b(x)$ we can now construct $\sigma(x)=a(x)^2+xb(x)^2$ which is the definition of $p(x)$ that is usually given.

Comment: thanks. you beat me to it.

Comment: @kodlu Apologies for jumping at this; I just love clever ideas like Patterson's.

Comment: no apology needed, I like your contributions...